# What is the command line argument to restart jboss via wildfly maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I would want to reload (restart) server jboss 6.3 eap that is running remote via maven plugin wildfly . I saw the documentation of wildfly shutdown, this command has a optional argument as reload as true to make restart of servers instead of full shutdown.
What is the syntax of giving this command along with optional parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn wildfly:shutdown -Dwildfly.reload=true -P 'profilename' -e`

This is the answer for my question, i gave this by trying it manyways. This way it works.

wildfly.reload - is the user property mentioned in the wildfly doc that we should use with -D flag.

profilename-- is profile id that we gave in pom.xml that identifies remote jboss server

-e -- for error logging.